# BindToRenderStep or Heartbeat for updating steps (ROBLOX)

Tags: animation, updating, roblox

I heard recently that ROBLOX came to stack overflow, so I thought I'd give this a shot. I heard that [`Heartbeat`](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/RunService/Heartbeat) is generally *better* than using [`BindToRenderStep`](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/RunService/BindToRenderStep) because it runs on a different thread, rather than scheduling a function to run before each render frame. I want to have all my animations, camera movements, and tweening to happen all in the same step, so it'd end up looking something like this:

```
-- Singular function to call that updates everything in 1 step
local function GameStep(deltaTime)
    Camera     :Update(deltaTime)
    Animations :Update(deltaTime)
    Tweener    :Update(deltaTime)
end
```

I'm just unsure about which listener to use to update all these events. I'm afraid that if it's too much work to process before each render frame (using `BindToRenderStep`), that everything will start to shudder, and lag. If anyone has some insight on which step updater would be better for a case like this, please let me know! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using localscripts, use

```
game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped()
```

Since rendering is done on the client.